# ComboBox Value Changes

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Soccer"
        .AddItem "Tennis"
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to make an `if` statement such that if the `ComboBox1` value changes either from nothing to Soccer/tennis or from one item to another 
then 
`Range("A1").Value = "This learner Plays Sport"`

the problem is I don't know how to do the part where the combobox value changes either from nothing to Soccer/tennis or from one item to another

I have tried workbook.change and it gives me an error the closes the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of workbook change event try the ComboBox change event like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value = "Soccer" Or Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value = "Tennis" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "This learner Plays Sport"
    End If
End Sub
```

To get to this change event just double click the combobox from the Worksheet and it will open the VBA editor for you.

This only tells you what the newly selected value is.  If you need to know what it was before the change it will be a bit more complicated.  You'll need to create a variable to  store/track the value to compare against once changed.

---

If you end up with a long list of sports, I'd suggest using `Select Case` instead of if statements.  For example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Soccer", "Tennis"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "This learner Plays Sports"
        Case "Lacross"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Something Different"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "value not in list"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much